# How can I return different field foreign key for two models related it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to retrieve the field full name for the field author in book creation,
and the nickname to retrieve in article creation.

models.py :

```
class Author(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="First Name",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        max_length=20,
    )
    nick_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Nick Name",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        max_length=20,
    )
   def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.full_name}"


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="book_author",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="article_author",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return in GET api, you have to modify **Serializer**.
Will be helpfull if you can elaborate where exactly you want to return.

**Form**

```py
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel # (Book or Article)
        fields = __all__

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["author"].widget = forms.Select(
            choices=self.get_authors(), attrs={"class": "admin-dropdown"}
        )

    def get_authors(self):
        authors = Author.objects.all()
        choices = [(author.id, author.full_name) for author in authors]
        return choices
```

Based on you what you want, you can use `author.full_name` or `author.nick_name`.

Comment: I'm using Class-Based-View.  I want the user will select the value in the form by the definition as described above